# Comment System Question

Tags: plugins, system, comments

I am wondering if somebody knows about a free (or cheap) php/mysql "plugin" comment system that can be added to any web pages.(beside commentics, old guy script or disqus, they are not exactly suitable for my purpose!)
I am interested in a comment system that allows replies, rating and allos also the user to load his/her picture.

Thanks,

Carly

Answer (score 1):

I used [facebook Comments](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) before and it works great. Btw ..what about [intense debate](http://www.intensedebate.com/)?